# Laravel force delete generates NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel

I have read as many posts as possible, but none of them can solve my problem.

The route:

```
Route::model('user', 'User');
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function() {
    Route::get('users/force-delete/{user}', array(
        'as'    => 'admin-users-force-delete',
        'uses'  => 'AdminController@handleUserForceDelete'
    ));
});
```

The html:

```
<li><a href="{{ action('AdminController@handleUserForceDelete', $user->id) }}">Force Delete</a></li>
```

The handler:

```
public function handleUserForceDelete(User $user)
    {


        $username_tmp = $user->username;
        $message = 'Success! User ' . $username_tmp . ' has been deleted.';

        if($user->trashed())
        {
            $user->forceDelete();
            return Redirect::action('AdminController@showUsers')->with('message', $message);
        } else {
            return Redirect::action('AdminController@showUsers')->with('message', 'User deletion error! Please try again!');
        }
    }
```

I tried to put delete and force-delete at the same handler, and the delete action took place but force-delete generated NotFoundHttpException. So I guess the problem is from the force-delete action??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!
For anyone with the same trouble, soft deleted user(or anything) will not generate an instance passed to the handler (or closure). Therefore, for this case I manually create an instance.

So instead of using this:

```
//will not handle soft deleted model.
Route::model('user', 'User');
```

Use this:

```
Route::bind('user', function($value, $route)
{
    return User::withTrashed()->where('id', '=', $value)->first();
});
```